# Using get_posts with arguments found in meta keys

Tags: custom-field, get-posts

I am using get posts, but I need to refine the query based on posts where a certain meta_key has a certain value.

Something like this

```
<?php $reviews = get_posts('post_type=reviews&numberposts=-1&   // eg. // location=berkshire');
```

Is it possible to do this and if so how?

Marvellous

Answer (score 19):

`get_posts` accepts any of the arguments that [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) accepts.  So there's a few options.

**1. `meta_key` and `meta_value`**

```
<?php
get_posts(array(
   // some more args here
   'meta_key'   => 'some_key',
   'meta_value' => 'some value'
));
```

**2. `meta_query`**

`meta_query` is more sophisticated that using `meta_key` and `meta_value`.  For instance, say you wanted to get posts that have the meta_key with one of three values:

```
<?php
get_posts(array(
   // more args here        
   'meta_query' => array(
      // meta query takes an array of arrays, watch out for this!
      array(
         'key'     => 'some_key',
         'value'   => array('anOption', 'anotherOption', 'thirdOption'),
         'compare' => 'IN'
      )
   )
));
```

There's a ton of examples for you to checkout in the [custom fields section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) of `WP_Query`'s documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its possible. Use `meta_key` and `meta_value` parameters. `meta_key` is for custom field key (e.g. location) and `meta_value` is for custom field value (e.g. berkshire).

Use the refined code below:

```
/* Query args. */
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'reviews',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'location', 
    'meta_value' => 'berkshire'
);

/* Get Reviews */
$reviews = get_posts( $args );
```