# Search custom post type by meta data

Tags: query, search, post-meta, query-variable

I have a custom post type 'Property' which my users need to be able to search by meta data.

I have 3 search functions - 2 on the frontend 1 in the admin area - 2 of which are running as expected and one which doesn't seem to be filtering results at all.

I think there may be a problem with either my definition or usage of custom query_vars.

In my functions.php I have the following:

```
function add_query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'bedrooms';
    $public_query_vars[] = 'type';
    $public_query_vars[] = 'location';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function meta_search_query($query) {

    $query_args_code = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'post_type' => 'nc_property',
      'meta_key' => 'nc_code',
      'meta_value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
      'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
    );


    $query_args_meta = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'nc_property',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'nc_bedrooms',
                'value' => $query->query_vars['bedrooms'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'nc_type',
                'value' => $query->query_vars['type'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'nc_location',
                'value' => $query->query_vars['location'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );

    if (is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
        query_posts($query_args_code);

    } elseif (!is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
        if ($_REQUEST["which_form"] == 'meta_form') {
            query_posts($query_args_meta);

        } elseif ($_REQUEST["which_form"] == 'code_form'){
            query_posts($query_args_code);

        }
    }  
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'meta_search_query');
```

Searching by the property code works no problem at all in both the frontend and backend however trying to filter results by the custom query vars - location, type and bedrooms - falls flat everytime.

An example query string which is created is as follows:

```
/property/?post_type=nc_property&which_form=meta_form&bedrooms=Two&type=Apartment&location=Bahceli
```

There is one property on the site which matches those details but WordPress returns all results each time.

Have I missed something?

EDIT: It turns out that because my search form for my meta queries was not using an element with `'s'` as its name the `$query->is_search` condition of my if statement was returning false, meaning my meta_query simply wasn't being called.

Kudos to fischi for spotting this for me! :D

Comment: Do the custom query vars get recognized by WordPress? If you `var_dump` them, do you get values for `$query->query_vars`?

Comment: Hmm the custom query vars are all returning NULL when I var dump them. Why would this be?

Comment: Probably because you have a mix of pretty permalink and `$_GET` variables. Can you try inserting the `$_GET` data instead of `$query->query_vars`? Do not forget to sanitize it if you are going this way :)

Comment: using `$_GET` returns the vars as expected: `array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "Two" [1]=> string(9) "Apartment" [2]=> string(7) "Bahceli" }` do you think a straight swap for `$_GET` in my functions.php will solve the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using get\_posts with arguments found in meta keys](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/using-get-posts-with-arguments-found-in-meta-keys)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, as you mix pretty permalinks with request parameters, I would use the `$_GET` variables in your query.

```
$query_args_meta = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'nc_property',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'nc_bedrooms',
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['bedrooms'] ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'nc_type',
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['type'] ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'nc_location',
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['location'] ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

Be sure to use the proper sanitation, depending on your needs, or using a function that checks for whitelisted values of the `$_GET` data.

Also check your function of the conditionals - you just alter the query if it is a search request (using `s` as search parameter), or alter the `if` statement.

Comment: I have made the changes you recommended however the search results still do not appear to be filtered whatsoever even though I know the `$_GET` variables are being picked up correctly when I `var_dump`...

Comment: Can you have a look at what query your WordPress runs? `<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>`

Comment: The query is as follows `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS north_posts.ID FROM north_posts WHERE 1=1 AND north_posts.post_type = 'nc_property' AND (north_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR north_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY north_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`

so it seems that my meta query is just being ignored? :/

Comment: ups, saw another thing - if you do not use the `s` parameter your condition `if (!is_admin() && $query->is_search )` is not met, as WordPress does not know this is a search. Try changing that too.

Comment: You are a WordPress hero! Making one of the search fields have a name of 's' has solved the issue!

Comment: Nice. I updated the answer :)