# Meta query not returning results even though the sql contains the information

Tags: meta-query

My page is not returning any results for my meta_query, just spits out the content in chronological order without applying the meta search. I am hoping you are able to assist.

PS - [This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131496/search-custom-post-type-by-meta-data/131509#131509) has already helped me a great deal.

So here's what my URL query looks like: /?petGender=Female (There will be more down the line, just trying to get this one to work)

I use a pre_get_posts action that checks for the GET variable as seen on [this tutorial](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/).
If it is present, it effectively adds the meta_query:

```
if( !empty($_GET['petGender']) )
    {
        //Add our meta for pet gender
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'gender',
            'value'     => sanitize_text_field($_GET['petGender']),
            'compare'   => '=',
        );
    }
```

Then, when I echo out the query (echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;) it all seems to have the necessary information in it. But it doesn't filter the results.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS db_posts.ID FROM db_posts INNER JOIN db_term_relationships ON (db_posts.ID = db_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN db_postmeta ON (db_posts.ID = db_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( db_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (11,12,13) ) AND db_posts.post_type = 'pets' AND (db_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR db_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (db_postmeta.meta_key = 'gender' AND CAST(db_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'Female') ) GROUP BY db_posts.ID ORDER BY db_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Any ideas?! Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure the post meta exists *and* it's set to `Female` and not `female`? Are you also 100% sure that the key is the same key you save your meta in?

Comment: I can see entries in the postmeta table, yes

`259 58 gender Female`

Comment: Perfect, and is `post_id` 58 assigned to taxonomy term 11, 12, or 13? Just trying to cover some of the bases as the code given looks acceptable.

Comment: Yes, 58 is assigned to all 3 of them, actually. 12 and 13 are sub categories of 11.

Comment: WOAH, NELLY! cybmeta's comment made me relook something and he is correct. I was doing a wp_query, instead of relying on the archive page to gather the information itself!! My search is now working! Please accept and apology for the time waste guys. :( But at least it's working now! hurrah! Thanks chaps!

Comment: It does beg the question, though, how do I make this work with WP_Query....?!

Comment: If this problem was solved, please submit the solution and mark it as such, rather than leaving the question unanswered. If you have another question, open a new question rather than posing it in the comments.