# Get_post() with meta_key when compare is a date

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, get-posts

This is similar to, but more specific than, the [question found here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/using-get-posts-with-arguments-found-in-meta-keys). That question suggests the Wordpress [WP_Query example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), which are helpful, but they're not working for me.

My code is as follows:

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_key'          => 'from_datetime',
        'meta_value'        => date( "F d, Y g:i a" ), 
        'meta_compare'      => '>',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'order'             => 'ASC'
    ));
```

The custom fields are made using ACF in our blog. The `from_datetime` field shows like this:

```
April 18, 2017 2:30 pm
```

So I've translated this to the date nomenclature:

```
date( "F d, Y g:i a" )
```

Events are a custom post type. Basically I want to show the upcoming 2 events that are NOT passed. So this is quite close to the example on the WP_Query page, but still the above doesn't work. The query returns nothing. I do know that if I remove the `meta_value` stuff above, there are four events to show that are beyond "now".

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrongly? The query seems correct according to the documentation at WP. Thank you!

Comment: I would note that this uses `WP_Query` internally, it may simplify debugging to use that instead by removing several quirks of `get_posts`. I would also note that meta queries are expensive, and queries that specify unlimited posts don't scale. Set a very high number you would never expect to reach, such as 100 or 200, rather than -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have error in your query. Please try this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'meta_key'          => 'from_datetime',
        'type'              => 'DATETIME',  // You can also try changing it to TIME or DATE if it doesn't work
        'meta_value'        => date( "F d, Y g:i a" ),
        'meta_compare'      => '>',
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
));
```

Comment: I think the `->` in your recommended code should be `=>`. This is after `meta_query`. Either way, I tried it, and it yields 0 results. Which is incorrect. Any other ideas?

Comment: You're right, That -> was a mistake. However, I've edited the answer a little. Please try again with this version and see if anything happens.

Comment: Thank you @Abdul. This works. However, what if I need to limit this to just the top 2 posts? Putting `posts_per_page` as 2 does not work. Perhaps because the "first 2" posts are NOT matching that `meta_query` condition? It's not a showstopper because I can get all the matching posts by leaving the count as -1, and then do a counter inside the foreach loop, and if the counter is `> 2`, then just `break`. But this is not elegant. Welcome any thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ACF Pro (e.g., using it's "Date and Time Picker" field type), or one of the plugins that adds a date/time field type to "normal" ACF (e.g., [Date & Time Picker for Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-date-time-picker/)).

If the former, it stores date/time values in `$wpdb->postmeta` like `2017-04-18 14:30:00`, regardless of the "Display Format" or "Return Format" specified in the field definition.  Thus, you should query as:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'from_datetime',
    'meta_value'        => date( "Y-m-d h:i:s" ), 
    'meta_compare'      => '>',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
));
```

If you're using one of the plugins that adds a date/time field type to "normal" ACF, you'll have to figure out how that plugin stores values and format `meta_value` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Paul. ACF's field is structured to store date in exactly that form, the one I included in my code. At least in the custom field definition screen.

Comment: @PKHunter Then you must be using one of the plugins that adds a date/time field type to ACF non-Pro, because as it says in the ACF Pro [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/), "The value selected can be returned and displayed in different formats but will always be saved to the DB as ‘Y-m-d H:i:s’. This format is used throughout the WP database tables and will allow for easy database querying."  Which means I have a typo in my answer (should be 'H' instead of 'h').

Comment: that may well be true. Let me try..